# Burninate [nosql]

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

I suggest that the [nosql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nosql) tag should be burninated.

Background: NoSQL is a very wide catch-all category for all kinds of database technologies which don't use SQL. It covers document-oriented databases like MongoDB or CouchDB, not-quite-sql table databases like Cassandra or Google BigTable, graph databases like Neo4j or key-value stores like Redis. Technologies which don't actually store data but interact with systems which do, like Hadoop or Lucene, are also sometimes put into this category.

When you look at the questions tagged as NoSQL, you mostly see two kinds of questions:

1. Questions about how to do something with one specific database technology. These questions are also tagged with the tag for that technology, making NoSQL a **meta-tag**. It's also a **redundant meta-tag** because following that scheme, every single question tagged as mongodb, couchdb, neo4j or cassanda could also get the nosql tag (in fact many of them do).
2. Questions which ask which NoSQL database to use for a specific problem. In these cases the question is often not tagged by just one but many different nosql database technologies - any the author could think of. These questions almost always get downvoted and closed because they fall into the "[Gorilla vs. Shark](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/)" or the "Which technology to use" category, making it an **off topic tag**.

Let's take the litmus test from the "[When to burninate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191)" meta-meta-question.

> Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

NoSQL is a very vague and badly defined concept without a theory as consistent as the relational database theory behind SQL databases. That makes it a very ambigous, almost meaningless, category. Sure, not as ambigous as many other tags burninated in the past, but still not very meaningful.

> Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

There are very few questions you could ask about NoSQL which are not either "which database is better" or specific to a single technology. The term NoSQL is very vaguely defined anyway, so there are few overarching theoretical concepts which apply to all of these database systems equally. And when they are, I would consider them more on-topic on Programmers.

> Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

Most questions about database technologies which are commonly grouped under NoSQL are perfectly described by the tag for the database technology itself. When asking a question about, say, MongoDB it makes not much sense to add the nosql tag just because MongoDB is a nosql database, because you would then add it to every single question you ask about MongoDB.

> Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

As said, NoSQL is a very vague concept anyway. All the different NoSQL technologies have few things in common. The only thing they do have in common is that they don't use SQL, but whatever they use instead is very different. In the rare cases where you find a question which is tagged only as nosql and is not a "which technology to use" question, you often realize that the user is talking about only one specific NoSQL technology which is the only one he is familiar with so he believes that all others must work the same way.

As a little random sample, here are the current 15 newest questions from the NoSQL tag. As you can see all but one of them either fall into my category 1 or my category 2:

- [How to perform millions of inserts,updates and selects in a minute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28832912/how-to-perform-millions-of-inserts-updates-and-selects-in-a-minute)
  A "recommend me a technology" question which already has 3 close-votes
- [What is the tradeoff in NewSQL solutions? Why would someone choose NoSQL over NewSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28831004/what-is-the-tradeoff-in-newsql-solutions-why-would-someone-choose-nosql-over-ne)
  Gorilla vs. Shark
- [NEST ElasticSearch c# how to Filter on Nested Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28819384/nest-elasticsearch-c-sharp-how-to-filter-on-nested-object)
  Perfectly described by ElasticSearch, nosql tag is redundant as it could be added to any question about ElasticSearch.
- [What is a good solution for cross datacenter master-master replication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28818790/what-is-a-good-solution-for-cross-datacenter-master-master-replication) "recommend me a technology", already 2 close-votes
- [NoSQL statistics type query with BaasBox - OrientDB 1.7.10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28812845/nosql-statistics-type-query-with-baasbox-orientdb-1-7-10) Perfectly described by OrientDB, nosql tag is redundant as it could be added to any question about OrientDB. Also suffering from the "Every NoSQL database is like my NoSQL database" misconception.
- [NoSQL quorum comparing to virtual sharding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28811685/nosql-quorum-comparing-to-virtual-sharding) Finally a question which is neither specific to one database or a technology request as it compares two different concepts which are used by different database technologies to solve the same problem. However, it is quite a discussion-oriented question which would fit better on programmers IMO.
- [Aerospike : LDT error in cross datacenter replication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28805047/aerospike-ldt-error-in-cross-datacenter-replication) Specific to Aerospike - nosql is redundant
- [using javascript to create queries in mongodb terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28802133/using-javascript-to-create-queries-in-mongodb-terminal) Specific to MongoDB
- [connection gwan with aerospike db in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28800136/connection-gwan-with-aerospike-db-in-c) Specific to Aerospike
- [CouchDB Compression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28789459/couchdb-compression) Specific to - you guessed it - CouchDB
- [Couch DB - Is Hovercraft still actively maintained?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28785406/couch-db-is-hovercraft-still-actively-maintained) Guess!
- [Cassandra CQL3 conditional insert/update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28779465/cassandra-cql3-conditional-insert-update) Specific to Cassandra
- [Asynchronous Oracle NoSQL client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28776233/asynchronous-oracle-nosql-client) Specific to Oracle NoSQL which has its own tag and which this question is also tagged with
- [Google Datastore - Not Seeing 1 Write per Second per Entity Group Limitation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28774980/google-datastore-not-seeing-1-write-per-second-per-entity-group-limitation) Specific to Google Datastore
- [Mongodb Deep Embedded Object Array Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28772412/mongodb-deep-embedded-object-array-query) Specific to MongoDB

Comment: IMO, this would be like burninating the `sql` tag. I'm not sure this is a worthy candidate.  Questions could potentially be answered in the `sql` tag or even the `nosql` tag without it being a specific product.

Comment: @bluefeet I'm not an expert in NoSQL technologies, but I do know that [SQL is an ANSI standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL:2011) (and of course every DB vendor has their extensions, but they do implement the standard); while AFAIK [NoSQL has no such standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9252034/is-there-an-emerging-standard-api-for-nosql-databases). Thus I could ask a question tagged only with SQL and get an answer that conforms to the standard and should work in all SQL DBs, but I can't ask a NoSQL question without specifying a specific DMBS.

Comment: @bluefeet SQL is something completely different because SQL is a standardized language. There is no such thing as a nosql standard, and there will never be, because all the technologies are just too different. And when you look again at some of the questions I linked (which you surely did in the 5 minutes between me asking and you commenting) you will see that **it is not possible to answer any of those questions without product knowledge**.

Comment: Filtered it down by excluding some databases: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nosql+-amazon-dynamodb+-couchbase+-redis+-marklogic+-azure-table-storage+-oracle-nosql+-aerospike+-cassandra+-mongodb+-orient-db+-couchdb

Comment: This proposal is getting very polarizing votes, but so far there is was only one argument written against it which was thoroughly refuted. I would be interested to learn why people believe that this tag should stay despite the reasons I pointed out. I fully understand that it isn't obvious at first glance why this tag should be burninated, especially when you aren't familiar with the topic. But I hope that my argumentation makes sense. When it doesn't make sense to you after reading it, I would like to know why you think I am wrong about what I wrote.

Comment: I came prepared to disagee, but the OP's argument won me over.

Comment: Refined my query: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nosql+-graph-databases+-riak+-ravendb+-amazon-dynamodb+-neo4j+-couchbase+-redis+-marklogic+-azure-table-storage+-oracle-nosql+-aerospike+-cassandra+-mongodb+-hbase+-orient-db+-couchdb 1749 questions without more specific tag

Comment: What's the hold up, exactly? Is it that something of this size would require more of a Herculean effort to clean up, or mod intervention?  Personally, I say burninate it; your argument is well thought out, sound, and I simply can't find myself disagreeing with it.

Comment: @bluefeet Most of times we need to squeeze OP for the DBMS tag because the `sql` tag don't suffice. Ansi SQL is a joke. For `NoSql`I guess it even worst because there are not even a try to standarlize it

Comment: Should we have a nosql tag? [**NO**sql] (that wasn't worth the effort)

Comment: Going along with jean's idea and @bluefeet's comment, if we are going to burninate nosql for the reasons mentioned, then why not also burninate sql?

Comment: @Bobort Because, as I explained, SQL is a standard while NoSQL is the absence of a standard. You could just as well propose "If we are going to burninate no-c#, the hypothetical tag for all programming questions about languages which are not c#, then why not burninate c#"?

Comment: @Philipp, NoSQL does not mean "an absence of a standard."  Vendors have been discussing standards, and even if the umbrella category of NoSQL will not have a standard, some of its subsets do have something close to a standard.  (e.g.  Document Stores)  See my comment below in Joshua's answer for links to articles discussing this matter.  Your comparison is not fair in that C# and SQL are very different.  Argument by analogy is a logical fallacy.  From what I understand, C# is only implemented by Microsoft.  SQL is implemented by multiple vendors, as is NoSQL.

Comment: @Bobort If such a standard for a subset of NoSQL databases is created and implemented in more than one database then I will welcome creating a tag for it. But that standard might be "a" NoSQL standard but not "the" NoSQL standard. It might be a standard for Document-oriented databases, key/value store databases, graph databases, etc.

Comment: @Philipp, I  agree.  jean was suggesting that we shouldn't even have an `sql` tag because those who wish to answer the question have to ask for a more specific implementation of it.  That seems to be the same argument you have for burninating the nosql tag.  So why not burninate both?

Comment: @Bobort I already said why in my comment 11 minutes ago. This discussion is going in circles.

Comment: @Philipp, sorry, but I didn't expect "something with a standard should have a tag" as an answer.  It's quite weak.

Comment: @Bobort there is vast difference between "SQL" and "NoSQL" and I don't mean the (SQL) standard. SQL is a language (that has a standard bu that is irrelevant) and also has several implementations (with minor or major differences). All these implementations are pretty much based on the same model (i.e. the realtional model). The "NoSQL" technologies and implementations are based in very many and vastly different models or no model at all.

Comment: [tag:nosql] is more inline with [tag:rdbms] semantically. so if you wanted to argue that it should stay, it is more comparable to the `rdbms` tag in spirit.

Answer (score -12):

I'm in support of this. I also find myself agreeing with the op.  EVAN SANCTIONS THE BURNATION, NOW LET IT BE DONE.