# Tags that generally need specific implementations

Tags: feature-request

I've seen a continuing issue where new users come and ask SQL questions tagged with only the [sql] tag. The issue is that almost every single time they are implementing product specific code or at least the answer would require/greatly benefit from knowing if they are using Microsoft SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL, etc.

I know there is instructions in the [sql] tag that provides guidance on usage and advice on using a product specific tag, but this has not curbed the overuse of the [sql] tag by itself.

### Feature request:

I would like there to be a way to require an additional tag if a given tag is selected. I'm thinking that when [sql] is chosen, they can't submit their question until they pick either a product specific tag or a generic tag ([iso-sql]?). I would think this would be a useful feature for other tags as well.

Comment: like this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274634/578411 ?

Comment: Users won't read, you have to force them to choose one. Now what happen if they choose the wrong tag?

Comment: @rene I know there is instruction in the SQL tag for this specific scenario, but that doesn't stop people from submitting. My suggestion would prevent that. They could pick the ANSI option, but I don't think if given a list, that is what the people would pick.

Comment: So you basically want to change *it doesn't stop them from submitting the question...* in the answer I linked

Comment: @rene Yes. They would not be able to submit a [sql] tagged question without a supporting tag; [sqlserver] or [oracle] or [mysql] for example.

Comment: Who would get to choose the (supporting) tags? How will they get chosen? Why not "simply" get rid of the sql tag if you can't use it on its own?

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/360728/burninate-sql

Comment: I'd read those linked questions/suggestions, but I don't actually think [sql] should be banned. It is the natural starting point for someone asking questions about sql. My thought is that the feature would help people answering as well as making it more obvious to questioners that it is super important to know what flavor they are using.

Comment: I mean... this really is a burninate request, actually more like a blacklist request. If you can only post a tag when it accompanies another tag then why even have original tag to begin with?

Comment: @Clint I see your point, but I see it more like a workflow feature. You pick [sql] and now you need to specify which variety.

Comment: Minor nitpick but your `ansi-sql` example should really be `iso-sql`, if only to avoid Americo-centrism ;).

Comment: @Clint Tagging SQL identifies the language, while tagging - for example - MySQL gives information over the dialect and constraints. If I search for SQL related questions, I will definitely also search for SQL, if only to look beyond my own dialect. And given the standard, there is a lot of commonality, the additional tag of the vendor just helps to narrow it down **when needed**.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel As an American, I would like to avoid international standards. Updated my post with your un-American suggestion. :P

Comment: This sounds like a lot of work.  You'd need some way to mark the tags that need supporting tags, and what those supporting tags are.  And you'd need to some way to allow adding a new supporting tag at the time the supporting tag is created.