# Should [scala] be removed in favour of [scala-2] and [scala-3]?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, retag-request

There is a growing issue with questions being asked about Scala 3 without the [scala-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scala-3) tag, but only the [scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scala) tag. Historically, [scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scala) refers to Scala 2 (the [scala-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scala-2) tag is moribund), but Scala 3 is becoming increasingly popular and will eventually become the default version of Scala.

The languages are sufficiently different that users may wish to exclude one or other version from their searches. Migrating the [scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scala) tag to [scala-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scala-2) would require questioners to specify the version in the tag and thus allow appropriate filtering.

Comment: I see very little use of the version-specific tags. Can _all_ [tag:scala] questions be retagged [tag:scala-2]? If not, how do you propose those ~107.000 are retagged?

Comment: Maybe leave everything be as it is? Having both generic and versioned tags in languages that are versioned helps contributors configure what they focus on better whereas the generic tags help identify version-agnostic questions. That said, the problem, as always, is the misuse of tags - is the problem really that significant to warrant a tag removal?

Comment: I think we shouldn't retag but make it very clear that you also need a version tag. It's a wonderful coincidence! Just after you posted this, I posted a similar thing but for SDL, I don't want the meta-meta effect, so I won't link it.

Comment: I guess the question is how do you "make it clear" that people should use the `scala-2` as well as (or instead of) `scala`?

Comment: How about going the other way: remove version tags and only leave plain scala.

Comment: So is it OK to add the `scala-3` tag to a question that is specific to that version but does not have that tag? What is the etiquette here?

Answer (score 4):

I disagree; the mere fact that there are different versions (even different versions with major changes) doesn't mean that the tag should be removed. If it did, we'd also have to get rid of, for example, the Python tag for the same reason (because version 2 and version 3 are very different). I would strongly object to that change, though, because I still find that tag helpful.

Another obvious counterexample is SQL, which effectively has several parallel vendor-specific versions, but we already [rejected that](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/360728/burninate-sql).

Comment: There are no version specific SQL, but flavors of SQL with extensions. ANSI SQL is almost always supported, unless you look for specific topics like window functions.